# Adding div around footer elements causes issue

Tags: magento2, template, xml, frontend

I'm trying to add a simple div around the copyright & bug report links in the footer. I can achieve this by doing this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
  <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
      <container name="copyright-bug" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bottom-links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" ifconfig="design/footer/report_bugs"/>
      </container>
  </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

This adds a div called bottom-links around the copyright and bug reports links but it removes all other elements such as footer links, header links, basket link. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a separate layout file in your Magento theme or in a layout file that is within a custom module, you may use a reference to the container "footer".

Like below:

```
  <referenceContainer name="footer">
      <container name="copyright-bug" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bottom-links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" ifconfig="design/footer/report_bugs"/>
  </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

To explain this answer, the `footer_links` block happens to be defined in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` and you will see, the block is a direct child to the container footer. Therefore you want to take its reference like above whereas using container node would redefine the container and therefore overwrite its previous chidlren